# Unpickler for class with tuple

Tags: scala-pickling

I recently came across this framework and it seems really promising for what I need. I am testing some simple examples out and I'm curious why I can pickle my object but it can't find an unpickler. Here is my example:

```
import scala.pickling._
import json._
object JsonTest extends App {
  val simplePickled = new Simple(("test", 3)).pickle
  val unpickled = simplePickled.unpickle[Simple]
}
class Simple(val x: (String, Int)) {}
```

*Cannot generate an unpickler for com.ft.Simple*

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is actually a regression introduced 3 days ago. We actually just resolved this and have pushed a fix less than 1-2 hours ago.

The code you posted above now works again:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.pickling._
import json._
object JsonTest extends App {
  val simplePickled = new Simple(("test", 3)).pickle
  val unpickled = simplePickled.unpickle[Simple]
}
class Simple(val x: (String, Int)) {}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.pickling._
import json._
defined module JsonTest
defined class Simple
```

I've also [added your code snippet here as a test case in our test suite](https://github.com/scala/pickling/commit/39485e8b7843451d57378e32472d39210a7ea85d)

If you're using the artifacts we publish on sonatype, you'll have to wait until the next artifact is published (tomorrow), or if you want the fix incorporated right away, you can just checkout and `package` scala/pickling with sbt and use the jar that sbt builds (sbt should print where it put the jar).

Comment: I pulled and packaged the latest code and it works now! Thanks for the quick turn around. I will now be trying this out on our larger project now. Hopefully it all goes well.

Comment: Great to hear! We're currently a developing project working towards a stable release (unfortunately for a short while longer we must release snapshots which cause all of these regressiony headaches for our early users). So please let us know if you experience any issues, or if there's somewhere you think scala/pickling is lacking – we're actively developing scala/pickling and would be glad to receive any feedback. Thanks a lot for trying scala/pickling out :)